# Autofac manual injection in ASP .NET Web API application with per request lifetime scope

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I am developing ASP .NET Web API application and I need to use autofac manual injection in custom class (not web api controller) with per request lifetime scope. I have been searching for solutions for several days, and have found only the suggestion to use HttpRequestMessage in web api controller [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/autofac/b3HCmNE_S2M)

In web api controller:

```
var dependencyScope = actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope();
var lifetimeScope = dependencyScope.GetRequestLifetimeScope();
var serviceObject = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(lifetimeScope ).GetService(typeof(IMyService)) as IMyService;
```

But I, as far as I know, I cannot retrieve HttpRequestMessage object (actionContext.Request) in custom class. I know this is some odd approach and I should consider using constructor injection, but I am trying to add autofac to already existing big project and not to break everything for this step (this will definitely be refactored later).
Could you please help me with this issue.

Thanks for all responses!

Comment: Do you have Dependency Injection into the Composition Root of the application? If so, you should be able to gradually work DI into the application from there downwards

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I have set Autofac DI in Global.asax. Also I have configured MyService to be injected with per request scope. It works fine with controller injection but in case of manual injection (using GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IMyService)) as IMyService) it's injected with SingleInstance (not per api request scope). This is a problem for my application

Comment: Where does it need to be injected into? Could you provide a brief code example of the problem? You generally *should never* need to explicitly resolve something from the container in non-infrastructure related code so if we can see an example of the problem, we may be able to help

Comment: I have a large project where almost all classes are created manually. Right now I am providing DI for some common business functionality of this application. In order not to break the whole application I need to inject new services manually in some code parts for these manually created objected. The code sample won't give you much information about my application. Constructor injection cannot be done without big refactoring.

Comment: I am having the similar issue but since DI framework is difference nowadays then what it was before. in the old days, DI code use container.resolve<T>(...) but the current DI framework try to remove this dependency as well so leaving the manual resolve step out of the picture. it makes sense for the controllers but not easy for the rest of the objects for the project.

Comment: in your case, you might want to create a global reference to the container.